# Edit links grayed out on tag wiki when no wiki exists

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, tag-wiki, edits

The links at the bottom are gray, which fools the unwary that editing is possible.

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-476102444.png

Answer (score 3):

They're always grey, actually. Just like the grey edit links beneath your question right now. We don't use grey links to indicate unusable links - we simply remove the links in the first place.

For actually empty tag wikis, you get a giant "Create Tag Wiki" button. It's only in this scenario, where there is an edit pending which prevents a new Tag Wiki from being created (much like how a post is edit-locked with a pending suggestion), that the button isn't visible.

Comment: Hmmm, I can see the parallel, but its a touch different in that the tags provide a visual separation.  The edit links on the tag wiki blend into the message...  Perhaps swapping the position of the links with the Code Language?  Or placing the "no tag wiki" notification in a highlighted area?

Comment: @Wont Perhaps instead, the text *above* the edit links shouldn't be grey itself. That's what I'd think. Perhaps paired with the highlight you suggest, both work to help distinguish that it's not merely a part of that huge announcement.